# Filepath with variable inside c++

Tags: c++, filepath

I am trying to use a variable in my file path.

I have succeeded in adding one for the name of the files, but not for the folder name.

```
string utilisateur, mot_de_passe;
int gr;

cout << " Entrer un nom utilisateur:"; cin >> utilisateur;
cout << " Entrer un mot de passe :"; cin >> mot_de_passe;
cout << "Choisir un groupe:"; cin >> gr;

ofstream dossier;
if (gr == 1)
{
    dossier.open("C:/Users/titib/Contacts/Desktop/Projet informatique/groupe/" + utilisateur + ".txt");
    dossier << utilisateur << endl << mot_de_passe << endl << gr << endl;
```

I would like to use the variable `gr` as the name of the folder.

```
dossier.open("C:/Users/titib/Contacts/Desktop/Projet informatique/groupe/**gr**" + utilisateur + ".txt");
```

Comment: So what is stopping you from doing it: `dossier.open("C:/Users/titib/Contacts/Desktop/Projet informatique/groupe/" + gr + "/" + utilisateur + ".txt");`?

Comment: Read about [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)

Comment: @FirstStep What's stopping OP? The fact that string literal + int no sense (in most situations) perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

This should work just fine:

```
std::string FilePath = "C:/Users/titib/Contacts/Desktop/Projet informatique/groupe/" + std::to_string(gr)  + "/" + utilisateur + ".txt";
dossier.open(FilePath);
```

Comment: Except that `gr` is an *integer* variable, not a string.

Comment: If i do that "gr" must be a class.

Comment: hmm nothing happen... 0 files created. Should i declare pathfile before or something ?

Comment: I think you need to debug it. See what is `FilePath` before you open it, then see if it was opened correctly.

Comment: Step through the code! If you are on Visual Studio use F-10 to "jump on each statement" one by one, then hoover your mouse on the variables to see what do they contain.

Comment: I'ts strange because "Filepath" Contain the right name but no file is created.

Comment: What is dossier?? And are you sure that `.open()` creates the file if the file does not exist?

Comment: Note that `std::to_string()` is only available in C++11 and later.  For earlier C++ versions, you can use `std::ostringstream` instead.

Comment: @BaptBnnt: "not working" is useless information.  You need to explain **what** is not working exactly. What are you expecting? What is happening instead? What errors are being reported?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert `gr` to a `std::string` before you can append it to another string.  Prior to C++11, you can use [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) for that, eg:

```
#include <sstream>

std::ostringstream oss_gr;
oss_gr << gr;

dossier.open("C:/Users/titib/Contacts/Desktop/Projet informatique/groupe/" + oss_gr.str() + "/" + utilisateur + ".txt");
```

Or, if you are using C++11 or later, you can use [`std::to_string()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) instead:

```
dossier.open("C:/Users/titib/Contacts/Desktop/Projet informatique/groupe/" + std::to_string(gr) + "/" + utilisateur + ".txt");
```

Alternatively, in any C++ version, you could use `std::ostringstring` to format the entire path instead:

```
std::ostringstream oss_path;
oss_path << "C:/Users/titib/Contacts/Desktop/Projet informatique/groupe/" << gr << "/" << utilisateur << ".txt";
dossier.open(oss_path.str());
```

Comment: thanks for that it is very helpfull. But still not creating any file

Comment: Then you are doing something else wrong. Did you verify the user's input is being read correctly? That the file path being passed to `open()` is accurate? That the target folder already exists? That your user account has permission to create files in that folder? `std::ofstream` will not create missing folders for you, use [`CreateDirectory()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855.aspx) or equivalent for that. And try passing the path to [`CreateFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx) directly to see what errors it reports.

Comment: user's input are corectly readed. What do you mean by accurate ? The target exists i'am sure of that .it work to create a file but not a folder and a file . i already try to create the file on the desktop without success... going crazy

Comment: As I said in my last comment, "***`std::ofstream` will not create missing folders for you**, use `CreateDirectory()` or equivalent for that.*" You claim "the target exists", are you absolutely sure of that?  What is the *complete* file path that you are *trying* to create?  Again, if you call `CreateFile()` directly, you can see what specific error code it actually reports. `std::ofstream` can tell you **if** an error happens, but not **what** error it is. `GetLastError()` can give you more information when `CreateFile()` fails.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i finnaly succeed to create a file.
Thanks to Remy Lebeau.

Actually i changed few things :

- gr is name groupe now 
  -groupe is a string to avoid conversion

i used filedirectory .
Here the code

```
std::ostringstream gr;

        gr << "C:/Users/titib/Contacts/Desktop/Projet informatique/" << groupe;

        CreateDirectory(gr.str().c_str(), NULL);

        dossier.open("C:/Users/titib/Contacts/Desktop/Projet informatique/" + groupe + "/" + utilisateur + ".txt");
        dossier << utilisateur << endl << mot_de_passe << endl << groupe << endl;
```

Thanks again.

Comment: Maybe you can avoid an error prone repetition: after `gr << ...;` add `std::string str_path(gr.str()); CreateDirectory(str_path.c_str(),NULL); dossier.open(str_path + "/" + utilisateur + ...`